# MIPS store word/load word

Tags: mips, instructions, instruction-set

have a really basic question here.
Can a register have both a value and an address. As in assuming i want to swap between values: 5 stored in t0 and 7 stored in t1
does this code work:

```
sw $t0, 0($t0)
sw $t1, 0($t1)
lw $t1, 0 ($t0)
lw $t0, 0 ($t1)
```

Sorry this might sound stupid

Answer (score 1):

Not really for all values, as `sw` and `lw` need proper alignment (valid addresses should be multiple of 4).

That is, your code would only work for values multiple of 4, and anyways it would be a bad idea to do so, because you would be basically write garbage on whichever address you are pointing at.

To swap registers without overwriting a third register you can use the following trick:

```
 xor $t0, $t0, $t1
 xor $t1, $t0, $t1
 xor $t0, $t0, $t1
```